# how to create unique user id(number) so that two person can't have same id in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to create unique user id(number) so that two person can't have same id in php.
whenever user register,he will got this user id. in sql it should not be repeated.
here its possible that number can repeat on same system or in different systems.
i want to use this $rnd as user's user id.

```
<?php
$rnd="";
 $rnd .= rand (1000, 100000000000);
echo $rnd;
?>
```

Comment: dont know why people degrade others asking que, this isnt bad answer, so +1

Comment: Mostly because this is trivial question OP can solve himself by doing very little own work and search

Answer (score 1):

Use an Auto Increment integer field in the MySQL table for your users. When you create a new user it will generate a unique sequential ID for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `uniqid`: http://php.net/uniqid Do not forget to read whole man page incl. warnings and user comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use GUID as Global Unique Identifier for php. [create-guid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)

Comment: COM package is not in core PHP.